# An open subset of $R^n$ can be expressed in only one way as a countable union of open connected sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Here is the theorem

[image]
As a reminder, a component is the maximal connected subset of an open set that contains a certain point $x$.

My problem is where he states that $B(x)$ is connected and concludes that it is in $T$.

Here's one line of reasoning:
We know there exists a ball $B(x)$ completely contained in $S$ but we can't guarantee that it contains only points in $T$ (it may contain points from other components). If it is completely contained in $T$ we're done, if not we consider the ball of radius $r/2$ centered around the same point and so on. If the process stops at some radius, we're done. If it doesn't, it means that a ball of arbitrarily small radius around $x$ contains points in other components which shows that the component $T$ contains only one point which is considered a closed set. How can we prove that the process stops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key result is: If $A,B$ are connected sets and $A \cap B$ is non empty then $A \cup B$ is connected.

If $T$ is a component it is connected. Suppose $x \in T$, then since $S$ is open, some open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ is also contained in $S$. The open ball is connected (in fact path connected). Hence $T \cup B(x,\epsilon)$ is connected and since $T$ is maximal we have
$T \cup B(x,\epsilon) \subset T$ and so $B(x,\epsilon) \subset T$ and so $T$ is open.

Comment: Why is the ball connected? If it contains points from two different components it can't be connected since components are disjoint.

Comment: Come on! A ball is convex, therefore connected.

Comment: It is path connected (any two points $y,z \in B(x,\epsilon)$ can be joined by a path $y \to x \to z$. It is fairly straightforward to show that path connected implies connected (similar to showing that the interval $[0,1]$ is connected).

Comment: How can we guarantee that it doesn't contain points from different components?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it'? Two distinct components must be disjoint by definition,

Comment: I mean the ball.

Comment: If $T_1 \cap B$ and $T_2 \cap B$ are both nonempty and $T_1,T_2$ are components then since the ball $B$ is connected that means $B \subset T_1$ and so $T_1 \cap T_2 $ is non empty and hence $T_1 = T_2$ by maximality.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No problem, these things can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If $B(x)$ would contain points from another component, let's say $T^\prime$, then $T \cap T^\prime$ would not be empty. Therefore $T \cup T^\prime$ would be connected: a union of two connected subsets whose intersection is not empty is connected.

In contradiction with the fact that $T$ is a component.

Comment: Why would the intersection be nonempty? Can't the ball contain part of one and part of another?

Comment: @Km356 You can modify the argument by letting  $T'=B (x) $.

Comment: $B(x) \subseteq T$. So if $y \in B(x) \cap T^\prime$, you also have $y \in T$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net No, $B (x)\subseteq S $. We need to prove $B (x)\subseteq T $.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how this proves the existence of a ball completely contained in $T$

Comment: A component of an open connected subset is open.